# Probability of obtaining the desired state in quantum linear regression

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I was reading today the paper ["Pattern classification with linear regression on a quantum computer"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07823) where the authors calculate in a final step the probability of success to measure the last qubit in the state $\left| 1 \right>$.
The state to be measured is given by
$$ \left| \psi \right> = \sum\limits_{r=1}^R \sigma ^r \left| v^r \right> \left| u^r \right> \left| \lambda^r \right> \left( \sqrt{1 -  \left( \frac{c}{\lambda^r} \right)^2 }\left| 0 \right> + \frac{c}{\lambda ^r} \left| 1 \right> \right)$$
and their given probability of acceptance is given by $$p(1)= \sum_r \left| \frac{c}{\lambda^r} \right| ^2$$
I have to add that the $\sigma^r$ are the Schmidt-coefficients and hence sum up to $1$. Yet I think that the probability is not correct (missing the sigma term in the nominator).
Can someone confirm me or maybe tell me why my calculation of the probability is wrong? My result would be $$\sum_r\left|\frac{c}{\sigma^r}\right|^2$$.

Comment: Given that $\lambda^r = (\sigma^r)^2$, your result seems correct. Typo?

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks @udrv , indeed i forgot to add that $(\sigma^r)^2 = \lambda^2$